# Lowering the character count of a QR code to increase the robustness

Tags: qr-code

I want to investigate the possibility of generating QR codes that are easier to read than the current standard 25 Char QR code. The purpose it to extract the QR code from lower resolution video feeds. I realize I will have to sacrifice either size of the code (bigger pixel = easier to read), or reduce the bit count of the code (more pixels per bit). Or a mix of both.

Before I delve into http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/ and learn it enough to experiment, I wanted to know if there is already examples of 8~10 character QR code generators. Or if something about the design of QR codes diminishes the robustness below the current minimum (25 chars) such that I would gain minimal robustness at the expense of bit density.

[edit]
I misunderstood the character limitations. Ignore the part where I mention the 25 character limit. Instead, refer to Ver1 as being the current lower end limit on complexity.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make the QR codes as simple as possible, I'd offer the following advice.

First, it's actually Version 2, strangely, that decodes most easily in my experience. Version 1 lacks an alignment pattern and so can't easily be corrected for perspective distortion. So, aim to stay within Version 2.

You can modify the EC level. Use the highest level that still lets you fit into version 2 with your data. The lowest level L is just fine, really.

Finally, note that QR codes have a more compact encoding mode for certain types of data. All digits encode quite well. It has an alphanumeric node which includes *capital* letters, numbers and some symbols. If you are writing a URL and can capitalize all its letters and it still works, do so as it will be able to use this more compact mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever text you want in your QR code.

This is just about the smallest one you can generate - contains a single character "0"

[image]

If you want a web address, you'll need to use a URL shortner - or already have a very small URL.

Here is the (non existant) URL shortner a.xx

[image]

It only contains 16 characters

```
http://a.xx/1234
```

So, use a URL shortening service like bit.ly and you should stay below your character limit.